# how to access model property in custom binding knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js custom binding for jquery ui tabs. I create an example fiddle

http://jsbin.com/ikidiw/7/edit

Here i am trying to set currentSelectedTab property of current model object in custom binding through allBindingsAccessor. But getting error that model obejct do not have currentSelectedTab function. Whats the problem ?

Comment: I don't have time for a full solution but as a starter, allBindingsAccessor() will return you all of the bindings in the current binding context, one of them being "tab". So the syntax would be var tab = allBindingsAccessor().tab - from which you could access tab.selected.

Comment: Please choose one of the answers as the correct one, if none of them are what you are looking for, tell us why...

Answer (score 4):

According to the http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html, the signature of the init function is like this:

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
```

Here viewModel is the model object that was passed to ko.applyBindings. So after adding that viewModel parameter after allBindingsAccessor in your init function parameters, you can change your code in the following way:

instead of

```
allBindingsAccessor().currentSelectedTab(ui.index);
```

you can write

```
viewModel.currentSelectedTab(ui.index);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the current model you need to extend your init function with a forth argument which will be the current view model object ([see the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)):

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {   
      var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});

      options.select = function (event, ui) {
            viewModel.currentSelectedTab(ui.index);

      };          
      $(element).tabs(options);            
    }
```

Here you can try it out:  http://jsbin.com/uwajus/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem seems to be you're trying to access the value by the viewmodel name instead of the binding accessor pointer.

You can try it :
HTML

```
<div id="ccftabs" class="uitab" data-bind="tab : { selected : currentSelectedTab }">
```

And in thne Javascript

```
  var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor() || {});
  options.select = function (event, ui) {
    options.selected(ui.index);       
  };

  $(element).tabs(options);
```

I think this is a good way to do that.